# Como extrair codigo em hexadecimal de um executavel compilado com nasm?

Tags: arquivo, assembly

Tenho um executável, criado em linguagem Assembly e compilado com NASM.

Existe um forma de se obter o valor, em hexadecimal, dos bytes produzidos pelo compilador, de modo que eu possa utilizá-los em um disassembler (ou seja, descobrir os OP codes gerados)?

**Código:**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    FILE *file;
    char *buffer;
    unsigned long fileLen;
    file = fopen( "teste.o", "rb");
    if (!file) {
        printf("erro\n");
    }
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    fileLen=ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    buffer=(char *)malloc(fileLen+1);
    if (!buffer) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory error!");
        fclose(file);
        return 0;
    }
    fread(buffer, fileLen, 1, file);
    fclose(file);

    for (unsigned int c=0;c&lt;fileLen;c++) {
        printf("%.2hhx ", buffer[c]);
        if (c % 4 == 3) {
            printf(" ");
        }
        if (c % 16 == 15) {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(buffer);
}
```

Comment: tenta expor melhor o que queres, tens de ser mais especifico, mostrar o que já fizeste em termos de código. "necessito do código" não é uma boa forma de começar, aqui ajudamos a resolver problemas que você tem a implementar. Veja [como perguntar na central de ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *file;
    char *buffer;
    unsigned long fileLen;

    
    file = fopen( "teste.o", "rb");
    if (!file)
    {
        printf("erro\n");
    }

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    fileLen=ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    buffer=(char *)malloc(fileLen+1);
    if (!buffer)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory error!");
        fclose(file);
        return 0;
    }

    fread(buffer, fileLen, 1, file);
    fclose(file);

Comment: for (unsigned int c=0;c<fileLen;c++)
    {
        printf("%.2hhx ", buffer[c]);

        if (c % 4 == 3)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }

        if (c % 16 == 15)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

    free(buffer);
}

Comment: ai esta o codigo ate o momento, ficou numa formatacao ruim porem acho q ao passar para um editor sera mais visivel.

Comment: Já editei a tua pergunta e pus lá o código.

Answer (score 1):

A linguagem ou o compilador que você usou pouco influencia o formato do executável final. Se você está no Linux, é bem provável que seja um [**ELF** (Executable and Linkable Format)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format). Já no Windows, será um [**PE** (Portable Executable)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable). Sabendo qual é o formato do seu executável (você pode também escrever código que possa extrair dados dos dois formatos (ou de outros), basta checar os bytes mágicos para diferenciar) você precisa extrair as seções.

Como isso é salvo no arquivo difere a depender do formato, mas há um cabeçalho com algumas informações gerais como a arquitetura, a tabela de símbolos e a tabela de seções. Percorra a tabela de seções e verifique as flags de cada uma. Os compiladores geralmente produzem algumas seções que não são código nem dados, como a `.comment`. Pelas flags associadas a cada seção você pode identificar as que contém código (pode ser mais de uma).

Assim você terá uma lista de seções de código onde três informações são importantes: O tamanho em bytes da seção, a localização na memória virtual (isso vai influenciar algumas instruções como a *CALL* se envolver seções diferentes) e o offset no arquivo. O código de máquina compilado pode ser lido diretamente do arquivo executável, lendo *tamanho* bytes a partir de *offset*.

Se você quiser saber nome de funções ou das variáveis locais vai precisar também da tabela de símbolos. Isso deve ajudar já que só pelo código não dá para separar funções de forma clara. Cada símbolo está associado a uma seção e aponta para um endereço de memória para onde a função ou variável começa.